# Way to not use a real bank account to test plaid integrations

Tags: integration, plaid

This may be a stupid question, but I'm trying to figure out a way to develop an application that integrates with Plaid's API without using a real bank account to test it. I'm not a US citizen and therefore I do not have a real bank account on the banks Plaid supports.

Is there a way to make this kind of testing without having a **real** bank account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this authentication API `https://tartan.plaid.com/auth` you can use following test credentials :
  'client_id=test_id,secret=test_secret,username=plaid_test,password=plaid_good,type=wells'

As given in documentation of integrating Plaid API into your Application,you can use this test credentials for testing purpose.

Follow this link for more information about it
https://plaid.com/docs/api/#add-auth-user

Comment: @ufdeveloper I don't believe so. With the new API (I am using 2018-05-22), I had to gain the access_token using the quickstart app, running it in Sandbox mode using the clientID, secret, and public key associated with my Plaid Account (in sandbox), then through the quickstart app's web interface, I chose Well Fargo as the bank and entered `user_good` and `pass_good` as the username and password, as per the instructions in my Plaid account. This gives me a sandbox account which periodically updates with new transactions.

Answer (score 4):

For sandbox mode, you can test with following details in plaid

currently in Sandbox mode. **Credentials** »

`username:` user_good

`password:` pass_good

[Docs](https://plaid.com/docs/sandbox/test-credentials/#sandbox-simple-test-credentials)

Answer (score 1):

This question may be old but there is an updated way of accomplishing this. When working in the sandbox environment, the option now also exists to have flexible item configurations and realistic-looking data. By using the *user_custom* and a json password that conforms to a [schema](https://plaid.com/docs/#custom-sandbox-schema).

For example 
username: user_custom 
password:

```
{
  "override_accounts": [
    {
      "type": "depository",
      "subtype": "checking",
      "transactions": [
        {
          "date_transacted": "2019-10-01",
          "date_posted": "2019-10-03",
          "currency": "USD",
          "amount": 100,
          "description": "1 year Netflix subscription"
        },
        {
          "date_transacted": "2019-10-01",
          "date_posted": "2019-10-02",
          "currency": "USD",
          "amount": 100,
          "description": "1 year mobile subscription"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```